# ESXi | Persistent Cron job | /etc/rc.local.d/local.sh writing directory to cron file

Tags: cron, schedule, shutdown, esxi

I am trying to create a persistent cron job (i.e. one that survives reboot). I have followed this guide:

https://virtuallyvtrue.com/2019/03/29/shell-script-to-automatically-power-on-a-specific-vm-which-is-powered-off-vm/

I created a shell file in this directory.

```
/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/power-off.sh
```

I've updated the root cron file:

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root

#min hour day mon dow command
1    1    *   *   *   /sbin/tmpwatch.py
1    *    *   *   *   /sbin/auto-backup.sh ++group=host/vim/vmvisor/backup.sh
0    *    *   *   *   /usr/lib/vmware/vmksummary/log-heartbeat.py
*/5  *    *   *   *   /bin/hostd-probe.sh ++group=host/vim/vmvisor/hostd-probe/stats/sh
00   1    *   *   *   localcli storage core device purge
*/10 *    *   *   *   /bin/crx-cli gc
00 0 * * * /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/power-off.sh
```

I edited the local.sh file to write the cron job and make it persistent.

```
/etc/rc.local.d/local.sh
```

Contents of local.sh

```
/bin/kill $(cat /var/run/crond.pid)
/bin/echo ‘00 0 * * * /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/power-off.sh’ >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
crond
```

When the system reboots, a new cron job entry is created, but it appears to be using the time/date `'*'` as wildcards and is dumping the directory structure into the cron file:

```
#min hour day mon dow command
1    1    *   *   *   /sbin/tmpwatch.py
1    *    *   *   *   /sbin/auto-backup.sh ++group=host/vim/vmvisor/backup.sh
0    *    *   *   *   /usr/lib/vmware/vmksummary/log-heartbeat.py
*/5  *    *   *   *   /bin/hostd-probe.sh ++group=host/vim/vmvisor/hostd-probe/stats/sh
00   1    *   *   *   localcli storage core device purge
*/10 *    *   *   *   /bin/crx-cli gc
'00 0 altbootbank bin bootbank bootpart.gz bootpart4kn.gz dev etc include lib lib64 local.tgz local.tgz.ve locker opt proc productLocker sbin scratch store tardisks tardisks.noauto tmp usr var vmfs vmimages altbootbank bin bootbank bootpart.gz bootpart4kn.gz dev etc include lib lib64 local.tgz local.tgz.ve locker opt proc productLocker sbin scratch store tardisks tardisks.noauto tmp usr var vmfs vmimages altbootbank bin bootbank bootpart.gz bootpart4kn.gz dev etc include lib lib64 local.tgz local.tgz.ve locker opt proc productLocker sbin scratch store tardisks tardisks.noauto tmp usr var vmfs vmimages altbootbank bin bootbank bootpart.gz bootpart4kn.gz dev etc include lib lib64 local.tgz local.tgz.ve locker opt proc productLocker sbin scratch store tardisks tardisks.noauto tmp usr var vmfs vmimages /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/power-off.sh’
```

Are the startquote and endquote symbols required in the local.sh file? I can see that they're being inserted into the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` file.

[image]

I'd really appreciate some help with this. I just need to power off my server at midnight and I can't believe it is this difficult.

Comment: The guide used incorrect syntax. It required " instead of ' in the /etc/rc.local.d/local.sh echo statement.

Answer (score 0):

The guide used incorrect syntax. It required `"` instead of `'` in the `/etc/rc.local.d/local.sh` echo statement.

```
/bin/kill $(cat /var/run/crond.pid)
/bin/echo "00 0 * * * /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/power-off.sh" >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
crond
```